# lock and unlock tables in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking

While a quite long operation I have a database to be frozen (= not to be modified by other sessions, users etc at any circumstances). It's not because I change the database itself, but it is important that it does not change meanwhile.
In MySql I can solve this with *table whatever lock for write*.

But I need a parallel solution for Postgres as well.

With

```
$db->query("lock table whatever in ROW EXCLUSIVE mode");
```

I apparently achieve the same as with *lock table for read*  in MySql, but how can I release the lock then, what is the parallel to *unlock tables*?

Comment: To release a lock, end your transaction using commit or rollback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually Release Postgres LOCK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304465/manually-release-postgres-lock)

Comment: To problem is, I want to prevent any other processes (users, sessions), from doing anything on the database while my script does something *else*. I see, that I missed *not* in the question... anyway I can just ask for the tables names and then build the query in the script...